# How to order_by a field in a model that belongs to another model in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

So I have these models:

```
class b
  :field boolean, :type => Boolean
end

class c
  embeds_many :a
end

class a
  belongs_to :b
  scope :sort_by_boolean, order_by(:b.boolean => :asc)
end
```

I tried doing something like that but it isn't possible. Is there another way to order this?
Another thing I can think of is to loop through it and create two different arrays one where the boolean is true and other where its false and combine the two. But is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it the looping way but would prefer if theres an easier way:

```
class c
  def sort
    not_true = []
    is_true = []
    self.a.each { |x|
      if x.b.boolean
        is_true.push x
      else
        not_true.push x
      end
    }
    not_true + is_true
  end
end
```